# alert a json response

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, datatables

I have the following `json` response I need to alert ***errors*** object through javascript.

```
{"sEcho":1,"iTotalRecords":1,"iTotalDisplayRecords":1,"aaData":{null},"errors":{"msisdn":"num\u00e9ro de t\u00e9l\u00e9phone non valide"}}
```

I m newbie with `json` and I couldn't find a way to alert my error rendered by my controller.

Many Thx

Comment: `"aaData":{null}` is not valid JSON. Otherwise: `JSON.parse(string)`...

Comment: are you able to get javascript object corresponding to the response you received?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// your json data
var s = '{"sEcho":1,"iTotalRecords":1,"iTotalDisplayRecords":1,"aaData":"{null}","errors":{"msisdn":"phone non valide"}}';

// change in json object
var obj = JSON.parse(s);

// get errors value
console.log(obj.errors);
```

Make sure that you have **valid json data**.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

```
var j = '{"sEcho":1,"iTotalRecords":1,"iTotalDisplayRecords":1,"aaData":null,"errors":{"msisdn":"num\u00e9ro de t\u00e9l\u00e9phone non valide"}}';
var a = JSON.parse(j);
alert(a.errors.msisdn);
```

It will display message of msisdn property of errors, as msisdn is child property of errors.